# Convert year-week to date condition to date where the week has max days for that month

Tags: python, datetime

Let me explain, I'm trying to convert the 5th week of 2017; 201705 to a date that belongs to February because that belongs to 5th week of the year.

So far I've been able to convert the custom date format to a date as follows:

```
import datetime 
d = '201705'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d+'1', '%Y%W%w')
```

Which then output, 2017-01-30 00:00:00

But is there a way I can convert the date to February and similarly all week numbers that belong to a month gets converted to that month

EDIT: 
What I'm after is if the week number is 5 then its February, ,if its 9 then its March - sort of week-month mapping but I've not found any way of doing that besides changing the year-week to dateformat

Comment: 01-30 is January not February

Comment: That is what I'm after, if week is 5 then its Feb, if its 9 its march - but is there a way to do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question enough :(

Comment: I'm not trying to nit-pick this situation but according to https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?country=1&year=2017 week 5 is in January, not February

Comment: Yes @NathanBlaine agreed, but we only have this way to convert day to date, is there a way we can find how many weeks are there for each month per year, for eg say Jan in 2017 has 5 weeks, and for eg Feb has 5 weeks to then 201710 is Feb and Not March. It's a strange requirement I know, but...

Comment: I'm not understanding your requirement (it is in fact quite strange). I'm going to take one more stab at it then see if anyone else can suss it out. Are you asking for a way to map weeks 0-4 -> Jan, weeks 5-9 -> Feb, weeks 10-14-> March, etc.... Irregardless if that week is actually in that particular month?

Comment: yes, that is correct and number of weeks depends on year for eg in 2016 the distribution maybe different that 2017

Comment: Please visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date and scroll down to "Calculating a date given the year, week number and weekday"

Comment: Choosing a `Sunday` rather than a `Monday` appears to give a result more in line with what you wish to achieve (although you would have to test on a range of dates) i.e. `datetime.datetime.strptime(d+ '0','%Y%W%w')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime 
d = '201705'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d+'1', '%Y%W%w')
month_from_date = dt.strftime("%B")
print(dt)
print(month_from_date)
```

Will output:

```
2017-01-30 00:00:00
January
```

I'm a bit confused as to why you are expecting February however, because 01-30 is, in fact, January.

You can find more formatting info [here](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 0):

A quick test of my comment, about choosing Sunday as the arbitrary week day rather than Monday.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d1=['201205','201305','201605','201705','201805','201905','202005','202105','202205','202305']
>>> d2=['201209','201309','201609','201709','201809','201909','202009','202109','202209','202309']
>>> for dat in d1:
...  datetime.datetime.strptime(dat+ '0','%Y%W%w')
... 
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 10, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 7, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 5, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 10, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 9, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 7, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 6, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 5, 0, 0)
>>> for dat in d2:
...  datetime.datetime.strptime(dat+ '0','%Y%W%w')
... 
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 10, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 6, 0, 0)                                            
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 5, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 4, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 8, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 7, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 6, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 5, 0, 0)
>>>
```

Your mileage may vary.
I haven't tested for weeks further into the year.